# VSCode duplicating brackets when I type

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type some bracket if a suggestion item from dropdown suggestions are selected, my vscode autocomplete that suggestion plus type my last character plus complete my bracket.

For example:

I type `console.lo`, that time vscode open the dropdown of suggestions and show me `console.log`, but I don't want to use it, I want to finish typing `g()`, it happens that vscode autoselect the `console.log()` function, then as soon as I type `(` it auto completes with `()` and also I type `()` which end up like `console.log(())`.

It only happens if I don't finish typing `log`, for example: `console.lo` (here I type `(` and vscode auto complete with `console.log()` and I end up typing again `()` inside of `console.log(())`)

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: typing `console.lo()` will give you an error, `lo not found on console`, what do you expect to happen when you type `console.lo()`, if there is a suggestion you don't want to use press `Esc` or `Ctrl+Z` if the suggestion is filled that you don't want

Comment: I'm confused. You seem to be saying that you're pressing both of those opening round brackets _yourself_. In that case, why would you expect anything other than the behaviour you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be 100% sure if this will solve your problem, because you may have extensions that are making your instance of VSCode completely different than mine, but in the VSCode settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) search for autocomplete, and check for any extension settings that may be overriding the autocomplete function in VSCode. As far as I'm aware, VSCode does not natively do what you're describing, so checking your extension settings(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or clicking the Cog in the bottom left and selecting Settings) should solve your problem. Let me know if that works!